# How to use Sitefinity without Themes?

Tags: asp.net, themes, sitefinity

We are building a site, and have no interest in creating multiple themes.  We intend to simply use plain old CSS and XHTML markup.

Is there any reasonable way to discard the notion of themes from Sitefinity?  Or is our best bet to just simply create a single, minimalistic theme and leave it at that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a main theme (~/App_Themes/Default) and then leave the directory empty.  You'll still be applying a theme to your Sitefinity pages & templates, but the theme won't have any CSS files associated with it, therefore it will be the same as having no theme.

Hopefully this helps.